# Last line on screen not showing state

Tags: default-settings

I'm going through the `vimtutor`, and in Lesson 2.1 I read

> NOTE: The letter  d  will appear on the last line of the screen
>   as you type
>           it.  Vim is waiting for you to type  w .

On my MacOS-default `vim`, I don't see it appearing on the last line of screen. What setting might control this?

Comment: try `:set ruler`

Comment: @klaus `:set ruler` did produce some status on the right bottom area. But it still is not showing the `d` after it's pressed. This does sound like a step in the right direction, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must `set showcmd` to see this